# Geth miner has 0 hashrate on private chain even with coinbase addr set and miner.start() called

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, private-blockchain, ethminer

I have a multi-node private chain and recently had to switch the networkId and the ChainID in the Genesis block to match in order to obey Metamask's requirements.

Now that I have made those changes and redeployed, it worked fine for me locally, but my Dockerized Geth nodes are not able to "Successfully sealed a new block" but is able to "Commit new mining work". 
Below is the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ethereum/client-go:v1.7.2

RUN mkdir -p /root/myChain/
WORKDIR /root/myChain

COPY Genesis.json /root/myChain/

RUN geth \
    --identity "myChainNode" \
    init \
    --datadir "/root/.ethereum/myChain/" \
    "/root/myChain/Genesis.json" \
    --ipcdisable \
    --mine --autodag --networkid 777 --nat "any" --gasprice "3000000"

EXPOSE 30303
EXPOSE 8545


ENTRYPOINT geth \
    --identity "myChainNode" \
    --datadir "/root/.ethereum/myChain/" \
    --ipcdisable \
    --networkid 777 \
    --rpcapi eth,web3,net,personal \
    --rpc --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpcport "8545" \
    --rpccorsdomain "*" \
    --nat "any" \
    --port "30303" \
    --etherbase "<myPublicAddress>" \
    --ws --wsport "8546" --wsaddr="0.0.0.0" --wsorigins "*" \
    --mine \
    console
```

When I `miner.start()` or `miner.start(8)` the response is `null`
I am connected to peers in my private chain and my hashrate is still 0.

AWS has the appropriate 30303 and 8545 ports open for my EC2 running it.

My local node is mining beautifully and it's run script looks like the following:

```
sudo geth \
    --identity "myChainNode" \
    --datadir "~/Library/Ethereum/myChain" \
    --ipcdisable \
    --etherbase "<myPublicAddress>" \
    --networkid 777 \
    --rpcapi eth,web3,net,personal \
    --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*" \
    -rpcport "8545" \
    --verbosity 3 \
    --ws --wsport "8547" --wsorigins "*" \
    --mine \
    console
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

I found out the reason this happened is that of the following:

When I first created the Private chain, I had run the initialization with a different networkId. As I talked about in the comments, I ended up changing it because of metamask requirements for CustomRPCs to have the networkID and the chainID match.

If you decided to change your NetworkID after starting your chain, you need to make sure that Geth Init uses your original NetworkID and then when you run/open your Geth node you put your new NetworkID. The chain was initialized on all your other nodes and it will not mine correctly since it cannot seal without having the same init config.

Answer (score 1):

A miner requires an unlocked account for sealing. It seems that you forgot to unlock account.

Comment: You don't need the account unlocked for it to seal them. I have verified it on other nodes. In fact, you don't need to even have any accounts loaded into the web3.personal, you only need to set the Etherbase/Coinbase to the address of your choosing...

Comment: But [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/37560/16048) and my own setup make me think otherwise :/ But still, I would get back after confirming myself.

Comment: Interesting, I would think it isn't the case that you would need to unlock any account in order to mine. I would compare it to working at a company, you give the company your bank account number for them to airdrop money into but you do not need to login in order to do the work. In either case, I have proved through testing on my end to be true. I wish I could give you a Proof of Work hash haha.

Comment: I have confirmed by the following msg `WARN [03-27|06:49:17] Block sealing failed                     err="authentication needed: password or unlock"`

Comment: That's so weird. It did not happen for me at all. I deployed fresh nodes on spanking new AWS instances and never unlocked anything and it works perfectly. Sorry man.

Comment: Its probably the consensus. It might be required for POA. Did u use POA?